# How can UV rays kick an ozone electron since its wavelength is much bigger than an atom?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

It makes sense that UV rays can fuse two base pairs of DNA since it's probably the right size (between 400 and 10 nm).

I imagine it happens when the bottom of the UVC wave touches one DNA base, at the same that the pick of the wave touches the other base (I guess the distance between both bases probably is the same as the wavelength). This creates a kind of electric current spark that fuses them. But if so, how/why does it knock out a single electron of ozone? And why it doesn't knock out also the nitrogen's electron of the next layer of the atmosphere (which would do the job of the ozone layer)? There are plenty of electrons to knock the whole way down, right?

Maybe I should see a photon, not like a wave but a particle with enough energy to quick an ozone electron, but not enough to quick a dinitrogen electron. But if so, I'm confused about why/when this logic applied but not the others?

Ps: I'm looking for a simple explanation (I did not study physics).

Comment: Actually, base pairs are much smaller than an UV wavelength, so the same problem (and solution) applies to them as to the ozone molecule. This is a domain where one must consider photons.

Comment: Your description of a photon fusing two DNA bases is macroscopic. Thus requires quantum mechanics. Also you can ask this question about any atom or molecule. Why ozone?